# How to navigate the text cursor in pythons input() prompt with arrow keys

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I want to reposition the text cursor in an python input() prompt

```py
msg = input()
print(msg)
```

When the user presses the left or right arrow key, the text cursor should be repositioned left or right respectively. This is to allow the user to edit the previously entered text.

Instead the arrow key values are printed `^[[D`, `^[[C` etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do this (importing readline will allow you to use the arrows) :

```py
import readline

msg = input()
print(msg)
```